# Defining virtual fields in peewee

Tags: python, python-2.7, orm, peewee

Suppose I have a peewee model which looks more or less as follows:

```
class MyModel(peewee.Model):
    a = peewee.IntegerField()
    b = peewee.IntegerField()
```

And I wish to add a property to that model as follows:

```
    @property
    def diff(self):
        return self.a - self.b
```

This is helpful sometimes; now, if `Object` is a `MyModel` instance, I can easily check its `diff` with `Object.diff`.

What I **can't** do is the following:

```
objects = list(MyModel.select().where(MyModel.diff < 17))
```

And this is since MyModel.diff is a simple property, and is probably always greater than 17. It is not an `Expression` like `MyModel.a < 17`.

It would be very nice to expose `diff` as if it was a field; so the user of that API will not need to know whether the specific implementation has `a` and `b` as real fields and `diff` as a virtual one, or rather `a` and `diff` as real fields and `b` as a virtual one.

Of course, my real intention is to use properties which involve, in some cases, much more sophisticated calculation that that presented on `diff`; an example is

```
@property
def complicated_property(self):
    if 17 <= self.a <= 173:
        return a_complicated_math_function(self.a + self.b)
    return another_complicated_math_function(self.a * self.b ** 2)
```

On the other hand, it can be a very simple property, such as

```
@property
def seven(self):
    return 7
```

This means it cannot, in general, be converted to SQL, but should rather filter the results after they are retrieved from the database.

Is that possible?

## Update

I've just discovered peewee playhouse's hybrid methods/properties. These provide a partial solution to my question.

For example, my `diff` method can become a `hybrid_property`, and work as expected. My `complicated_property` cannot become one, or at least it seems like it; the `if` condition in its beginning will return either `True` or `False` constantly, and will not act as a function.

Peewee probably has some more magic hiding there; I'll keep looking and report my findings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like `hybrid_property` will be what you're looking for. Here is [the hybrid methods documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#hybrid)

As to your update, if you had just read a little further in the docs...

```
@hybrid_property
def radius(self):
    return abs(self.length) / 2

@radius.expression
def radius(cls):
    return fn.ABS(cls.length) / 2
```

So there you see two functions for the same property, `radius`. The first function will be invoked when called on the model instance. The second when called in a query.

You might write:

```
@hybrid_property
def complicated_property(self):
    if 17 <= self.a <= 173:
        return a_complicated_math_function(self.a + self.b)
    return another_complicated_math_function(self.a * self.b ** 2)

@complicated_property.expression
def complicated_property(cls):
    # Here you will need to use a CASE statement most likely.
    # If you want to turn it into SQL, you obviously need to know
    # what SQL you want to turn it into...
    return case(
        None,
        (cls.a.between(17, 173), fn.math(fn.more_math(cls.a, 1.23))),
        default=fn.another_complicated_math(cls.a))
```

Comment: Thanks! And I accept your criticism as well... and thanks for peewee!